# Qt Visual Studio, как удалить ui компонент

Tags: c++, qt, ui

подскажите пожалуйста, как удалить Ui форму из памяти в Visual Studio, пишет ошибку, выражение должно представлять собой указатель на полный тип объекта. В Qt Creator такой проблемы не было.

[image: qt]

[image: Qt]

Comment: Подключи заголовочный файл, того, что там у тебя в этой переменной.

Comment: Здравствуйте, спасибо что ответили, там уже подключен он #include "GUIStopCPP.h", в этом файле подключен ui компонент, вот что в этом файле

#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include "ui_GUIStopCPP.h"

class GUIStopCPP : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    GUIStopCPP(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~GUIStopCPP();

private:
    Ui::GUIStopCPPClass ui;
};

Comment: все разобрался, там по другому класс называется, не так как в qt creator

Comment: Хммм, а вообще можешь удалить деструктор, т.к. у тебя там нет выделения памяти в куче.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался, переписал и все указал, просто немного с названиями перепутал, в qt creator class называется по другому